# Find all tags within the first outer tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do you find all tr tags within the first tag with id 'foo'?

```
<div class="foo">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</div>
```

I've tried

```
var rows = $("#foo").find('tr');
var rows = $("#foo")[0].find('tr'); //trying to only grab the first div or n'th one
  for(i in rows) {
     console.log(i.innerHTML);
  }
```

My problem is that I can't select the first div and then search within that div to find all the tr within it.

Comment: A `<tr>` should not be a child of a `<div>`, fix your HTML first

Comment: `$("#foo")` looks for an element with an `id` of `foo` but your `<div>` has a `class` of `foo`. Try changing `#foo` to `.foo`.

Comment: Yeah, there should be a ... between div and tr; the actual html is very messy from the page I'm parsing from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the selector all at once to select all the elements. Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#foo tr").each(function(i, el) {
    $(el).attr("id", "row-" + (i + 1));
    console.log($(el).html().trim());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="foo">
  <tr>
    <td>Item 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Item 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Using CSS Selectors, you can select all the `<tr>` elements within the element that has id `foo`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, a `<tr>` element should not be a child of a `<div>` element.

That said, you just need to get the [children](https://api.jquery.com/children/) by element type - i.e.

```
$(".foo").children("tr");
```

Notice too your `<div>` has the `class` "foo" not the `id` "foo"!

Really your HTML should be more like this if you want to select on id.

```
<table id="foo">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</table>
```

Then your selection would be...

```
$("#foo").children("tr");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you are going with `div` :

```
<div class="foo">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</div>

var rows = $(".foo").find('tr');
$.each( rows , function( i, l ){
  console.log( "Index #" + i + ": " + l );
});
```

This will give you all 'tr' under your div with the class 'foo' .

But like others said , fix the html first. Use the `table` tag like :

```
<table id="foo">
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
  <tr>...</tr>
</table>

var rows = $("#foo").find('tr');
$.each( rows , function( i, l ){
  console.log( "Index #" + i + ": " + l );
});
```